# unresolved external symbol __imp__fread when changing from MS Visual C++ Compiler to Intel C++ 19.1 Compiler

Tags: c++, linker-errors

Have a project that is using [freetype263.lib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/freetype/files/freetype2/2.6.3/), it compiles fine with Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler in Visual Studio 2019, but when try to compile a C++ project with Intel C++ 19.1 compiler in Visual Studio 2019 get these errors:

```
1>freetype263.lib(ftsystem.obj) : : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fread referenced in function _ft_ansi_stream_io
1>freetype263.lib(ftsystem.obj) : : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fseek referenced in function _ft_ansi_stream_io
1>freetype263.lib(ftsystem.obj) : : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ftell referenced in function _FT_Stream_Open
```

There is also some warnings, although I'm not sure if these are important:

```
 1>LINK : : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : : warning LNK4286: symbol '_qsort' defined in 'libucrt.lib(qsort.obj)' is imported by 'freetype263_intel.lib(psaux.obj)'
1>LINK : : warning LNK4286: symbol '_qsort' defined in 'libucrt.lib(qsort.obj)' is imported by 'freetype263_intel.lib(type1.obj)'
1>LINK : : warning LNK4217: symbol '_qsort' defined in 'libucrt.lib(qsort.obj)' is imported by 'freetype263_intel.lib(ftbase.obj)' in function '_FT_Raccess_Get_DataOffsets.'
1>LINK : : warning LNK4286: symbol '_qsort' defined in 'libucrt.lib(qsort.obj)' is imported by 'freetype263_intel.lib(bdf.obj)'
1>LINK : : warning LNK4286: symbol '_qsort' defined in 'libucrt.lib(qsort.obj)' is imported by 'freetype263_intel.lib(sfnt.obj)'
1>LINK : : warning LNK4286: symbol '_qsort' defined in 'libucrt.lib(qsort.obj)' is imported by 'freetype263_intel.lib(psmodule.obj)'
1>LINK : : warning LNK4217: symbol '_strncpy' defined in 'libucrt.lib(strncpy.obj)' is imported by 'freetype263_intel.lib(ftbase.obj)' in function '_raccess_make_file_name'
1>LINK : : warning LNK4217: symbol '_malloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(malloc.obj)' is imported by 'freetype263_intel.lib(ftsystem.obj)' in function '_ft_alloc'
1>LINK : : warning LNK4217: symbol '_realloc' defined in 'libucrt.lib(realloc.obj)' is imported by 'freetype263_intel.lib(ftsystem.obj)' in function '_ft_realloc'
1>LINK : : warning LNK4217: symbol '_free' defined in 'libucrt.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'freetype263_intel.lib(ftsystem.obj)' in function '_ft_free'
1>LINK : : warning LNK4217: symbol '_fclose' defined in 'libucrt.lib(fclose.obj)' is imported by 'freetype263_intel.lib(ftsystem.obj)' in function '_ft_ansi_stream_close'
1>LINK : : warning LNK4217: symbol '_fopen' defined in 'libucrt.lib(fopen.obj)' is imported by 'freetype263_intel.lib(ftsystem.obj)' in function '_FT_Stream_Open'
1>LINK : : warning LNK4217: symbol '___stdio_common_vsprintf' defined in 'libucrt.lib(output.obj)' is imported by 'freetype263_intel.lib(bdf.obj)' in function '__bdf_parse_properties'
1>LINK : : warning LNK4217: symbol '_atol' defined in 'libucrt.lib(atox.obj)' is imported by 'freetype263_intel.lib(type42.obj)' in function '_T42_GlyphSlot_Load'
1>LINK : : warning LNK4286: symbol '_atol' defined in 'libucrt.lib(atox.obj)' is imported by 'freetype263_intel.lib(type1cid.obj)'
```

I have recompiled the freetype project using Intel 19.1 compiler which outputs a .lib file, and that succeeds but still doesn't fix issue.

The freetype project has code like this:

Excerpt from include file:

```
#define ft_ptrdiff_t  ptrdiff_t


  /**********************************************************************/
  /*                                                                    */
  /*                           integer limits                           */
  /*                                                                    */
  /* UINT_MAX and ULONG_MAX are used to automatically compute the size  */
  /* of `int' and `long' in bytes at compile-time.  So far, this works  */
  /* for all platforms the library has been tested on.                  */
  /*                                                                    */
  /* Note that on the extremely rare platforms that do not provide      */
  /* integer types that are _exactly_ 16 and 32 bits wide (e.g. some    */
  /* old Crays where `int' is 36 bits), we do not make any guarantee    */
  /* about the correct behaviour of FT2 with all fonts.                 */
  /*                                                                    */
  /* In these case, `ftconfig.h' will refuse to compile anyway with a   */
  /* message like `couldn't find 32-bit type' or something similar.     */
  /*                                                                    */
  /**********************************************************************/


#include <limits.h>

#define FT_CHAR_BIT    CHAR_BIT
#define FT_USHORT_MAX  USHRT_MAX
#define FT_INT_MAX     INT_MAX
#define FT_INT_MIN     INT_MIN
#define FT_UINT_MAX    UINT_MAX
#define FT_LONG_MAX    LONG_MAX
#define FT_ULONG_MAX   ULONG_MAX


  /**********************************************************************/
  /*                                                                    */
  /*                 character and string processing                    */
  /*                                                                    */
  /**********************************************************************/


#include <string.h>

#define ft_memchr   memchr
#define ft_memcmp   memcmp
#define ft_memcpy   memcpy
#define ft_memmove  memmove
#define ft_memset   memset
#define ft_strcat   strcat
#define ft_strcmp   strcmp
#define ft_strcpy   strcpy
#define ft_strlen   strlen
#define ft_strncmp  strncmp
#define ft_strncpy  strncpy
#define ft_strrchr  strrchr
#define ft_strstr   strstr


  /**********************************************************************/
  /*                                                                    */
  /*                           file handling                            */
  /*                                                                    */
  /**********************************************************************/


#include <stdio.h>

#define FT_FILE     FILE
#define ft_fclose   fclose
#define ft_fopen    fopen
#define ft_fread    fread
#define ft_fseek    fseek
#define ft_ftell    ftell
#define ft_sprintf  sprintf


  /**********************************************************************/
  /*                                                                    */
  /*                             sorting                                */
  /*                                                                    */
  /**********************************************************************/


#include <stdlib.h>

#define ft_qsort  qsort
```

Excerpt from .c file used to generate lib:

```
  /*************************************************************************/
      /*                                                                       */
      /* <Function>                                                            */
      /*    ft_ansi_stream_io                                                  */
      /*                                                                       */
      /* <Description>                                                         */
      /*    The function to open a stream.                                     */
      /*                                                                       */
      /* <Input>                                                               */
      /*    stream :: A pointer to the stream object.                          */
      /*                                                                       */
      /*    offset :: The position in the data stream to start reading.        */
      /*                                                                       */
      /*    buffer :: The address of buffer to store the read data.            */
      /*                                                                       */
      /*    count  :: The number of bytes to read from the stream.             */
      /*                                                                       */
      /* <Return>                                                              */
      /*    The number of bytes actually read.  If `count' is zero (this is,   */
      /*    the function is used for seeking), a non-zero return value         */
      /*    indicates an error.                                                */
      /*                                                                       */
      FT_CALLBACK_DEF( unsigned long )
      ft_ansi_stream_io( FT_Stream       stream,
                         unsigned long   offset,
                         unsigned char*  buffer,
                         unsigned long   count )
      {
        FT_FILE*  file;
    
    
        if ( !count && offset > stream->size )
          return 1;
    
        file = STREAM_FILE( stream );
    
        if ( stream->pos != offset )
          ft_fseek( file, (long)offset, SEEK_SET );
    
        return (unsigned long)ft_fread( buffer, 1, count, file );
      }
```

Comment: I think your problem is ***warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library*** To me this means you have more  than 1 CRT

Comment: You can't mix code that was compiled with /MD (like freetype was, the CRT lives in its own DLL) with code compiled with /MT (the rest of the program, the CRT gets linked in).  /MT is only appropriate for small programs without complicated dependencies.  https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/linking-or-linker-options/md.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the issue I changed project properties **C/C++** - **Code Generation** from **Multi-Threaded (/MT)** to **Multi-Threaded DLL (/MD)**

This removed all linker errors but then got error **setup.sbr** not found. This was fixed by configuration project properties **C/C++** - **Browse Information** - **Enable Browse Information** to **No**